# Good volts and amps but phone still charging slowly

Tags: power, batteries, usb, dc, android

I am really new to the EE game and am still tinkering. I have built my own portable DC power source similar to a [Minty Boost](https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost) from scratch and plugged it into the USB port of my Galaxy S3 and it charges the phone but soooo slowly. I measured 5.02V DC and 650mA on the output, but the charge rate is abysmal and it nearly depletes the minty boost. Any thoughts as to why the charge rate is so bad?  Should I check the power quality with an oscilloscope? What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using the Galaxy S3 (e.g. playing games, watching videos, browsing the internet) as you are charging it, I think the power consumption might be too much (quantitatively it might be close to (5 V)*(0.65 A) = 3.25 W which is drawn from the portable charger). From [here](http://www.itproportal.com/2012/07/12/lab-tests-confirm-samsung-galaxy-s3-is-a-display-dimwit/) you can see that, even the screen itself might be pulling 1.3 Watts of power itself, when it is fully illuminated.

Comment: @ acm - thanks but in this case the phone is in low power state: not it use, screen off.

Answer (score 1):

The phone restricts itself to a low-current charge if the source does not indicate that it is a dedicated power supply, by tying the data pins together with a fairly low resistance.

Technically, your phone is in the wrong for using more than 100mA without asking first, and it also exceeds the 500mA that are allowed in the USB specification. In practice, these work in almost all cases because no one implements the restrictions that tightly.

The 1.3A specified for quick charging however would be far enough above the limit that several USB host implementations would detect this as a short and shut down the port, hence the additional requirement to short out the USB data pins on the power supply side to indicate a high current capable source.

Comment: great response. i shorted the data pins without a resister on the usb cable going to the phone. Would that be enough to invoke the quick charge? also how would my phone "ask" to draw more than 100aA?

Comment: It should work, but you are then leaking a bit of power through the 1,5kOhm resistors connecting D+/D- to 5V/GND on the USB side.

Comment: The upgrade from 100mA to 500mA is in the USB protocol. Before enumeration and configuration, devices may pull a maximum of 100mA (which is also why USB hubs typically have four downstream ports).

Comment: You can ignore that upgrade for quick charge -- the high current setup is specifically designed for when you do not want an USB stack, and as the data pins are unusable, there is nothing to negotiate over.

Comment: Is it even worth the effort to worry about the 1,5kOhm resistors? the relative power leak seems minimal.

Comment: Only for heat dissipation. There is also a good chance that the D+ resistor is switchable and might be disconnected during high-current charging, at which point there is no problem at all.

Comment: IIRC the spec suggests some resistance (keep in mind that a regular USB host has 30kOhm here, so it cannot be too high) mainly as a protection for devices that aren't prepared for the data lines to be shorted, i.e. devices other than your phone.

Comment: sweet. is it necessary for my device to enumerate before it draws 500mA? how is that accomplished? is it a software issue at that point - usb stack stuff?

Comment: The correct approach for a device is to have a circuit to detect quick charge capability (shorted pins), and if that is not present, it has to present itself as an USB device and wait for enumeration before starting to charge. There are off-the-shelf USB controllers that can do that.

Comment: Quite a lot of devices do it wrong, such as your phone. If you connected your phone to a bus powered USB hub which already had a mouse, keyboard and flash drive connected, the hub would go over its power budget. If the device waits for configuration in such a case, it will not start to charge, and the user should be presented with a dialog "insufficient power to enable device", which is probably as helpful as it can get.

Comment: hmm, ok. and switching it up for a second, should i also investigate the power quality to confirm that my power source is supplying pure square wave DC to the phone? Oscilloscope time?

Comment: It should be supplying pure DC, ideally. Two buck converters fighting each other over the voltage in the middle is a bad idea, so there should be enough capacitance to stabilize the voltage.

Comment: excellent. I will proceed as you suggest. i would love to pick your brain a bit more but i need to implement this information first. i am too new to stack to upvote or chat so all i can do is say thanks a million for your time :)

Comment: A quick question regarding usb-otg host negotiation. is there any snippets of code out there that i can bake into a quick and dirty android app that can then allow the 500mA current draw?

Comment: That is going to be on the driver level. When your phone is running as a device, having a descriptor with a bus powered 500mA configuration is sufficient. When your phone is supplying another device, the host part of the OTG driver decides whether to configure the device, and AFAIK the default is to allow it for devices directly connected.

Comment: Thanks. What is the criteria for the host part of the OTG driver "deciding" to configure the device for high current draw? How exactly can i enable this high current draw in my project?

Comment: The driver attempts to enable and configure all devices. Each port has 500mA maximum, so if a single device is hanging off it asking for 500mA, that is fine, but if there is an unpowered hub on that port, only 400mA are available for downstream devices, so 500mA bus powered configurations cannot be used, so the device is not enabled.

Comment: This is very applicable there is effectively an "unpowered hub" between a-device and b-device, which means i have a max of 400mA available to b-device via the hub. how do i configure b-device to request 400mA? i could really use some actionable direction.

Comment: You can't. The device lists its demands, and the host decides whether it can meet them.

Comment: ok, so if devices can request their current needs,  why can't my b-device request more than 100mA?

Comment: You'd create a configuration descriptor that asks for 400mA. The main problem is that the configuration descriptor is fixed, and there is no negotiation (well, technically you could create five different configurations, and see which one was activated, but I'm not sure how well that works in the real world).

Comment: This is exactly the information i was looking for. Thanks!  How is there no negotiation?

Comment: The normal use case for USB doesn't have a need for negotiation, because devices have a specific purpose and their power demands are known when they are built.

Comment: Ok, that corresponds with what i have found. You have been a huge help.

Comment: so then I should be able to integrate a host controller IC into my hub circuitry, configure the descriptor values, including the bMaxPower value and then if the configuration was done correctly my a-device should be able to enumerate my hub and supply 500mA?

Comment: I'd check for a readymade solution here -- Texas Instruments has [a few interesting ICs](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slyt509b/slyt509b.pdf).